# Download file from url (in list)

Tags: python, pdf

I'm scraping google for pdf files (whitepapers) and would like to have them saved as files instead of listed in the console.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
import  requests, re
from    docopt import docopt
from    bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from    time import time as timer
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve, quote
from urllib.parse import urljoin

def get_urls(search_string, start):
    #Empty temp List to store the Urls
    temp        = []
    url         = 'https://www.google.com/search'
    payload     = { 'q' : search_string, 'start' : start }
    my_headers  = { 'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/11.0' }
    r           = requests.get( url, params = payload, headers = my_headers )
    soup        = BeautifulSoup( r.text, 'html.parser' )
    h3tags      = soup.find_all( 'h3', class_='r' )
    for h3 in h3tags:
        try:
            temp.append( re.search('url\?q=(.+?)\&sa', h3.a['href']).group(1) )
        except:
            continue
    return temp

def main():
    start     = timer()
    #Empty List to store the Urls
    result    = []
    arguments = docopt( __doc__, version='MakMan Google Scrapper & Mass Exploiter' )
    search    = arguments['<search>']
    pages     = arguments['<pages>']
    #Calling the function [pages] times.
    for page in range( 0,  int(pages) ):
        #Getting the URLs in the list
        result.extend( get_urls( search, str(page*10) ) )
    #Removing Duplicate URLs
    result    = list( set( result ) )
    print( *result, sep = '\n' )
    print( '\nTotal URLs Scraped : %s ' % str( len( result ) ) ) 
    print( 'Script Execution Time : %s ' % ( timer() - start, ) ) 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


#End
```

I tried adding:

```
with open ('file.txt', 'w') as f:
   print( *result, file=f)
```

at the end to parse it to a file, but I'm certain there's an easier way to download the pdf files without first saving the links to a file.

Comment: wouldn't you just do `urlopen` for each url you found then save the contents to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the urls to the PDF files, you can use `urllib.urlretrieve()` like so. This will download the file to the current working directory keeping its name. Of course, you can specify whatever target path you like.

```
from os import path
from urllib import urlretrieve
from urlparse import urlparse

src_url = 'http://path/to/document.pdf'
tgt_path = path.split(urlparse(src_url).path)[-1]
urlretrieve(src_url, tgt_path)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!
Here's the code I added:
`url_list = result
    for line in url_list:
        try:
            src_url = line
            tgt_path = path.split(urlparse(src_url).path)[-1]
            urlretrieve(src_url, tgt_path)
        except:
            continue`